# Find tags with no classes and add a class

Tags: jquery, class

I need jQuery to add a class to any form element that has no class allready. I made up a function, the hasNoClass.

Is it possible to do in the real life?
Pseudo code: add class to "classless" form tag
jQuery("form").hasNoClass().addClass("gotClass");

Alternatively it can be done by a "add class to 3rd form start tag on page. No clue how that would be either, but there may be a position or count function
Pseudo code: add class to third form tag:
jQuery("form").postition("3").addClass("gotClass");

Wow! That was two questions! I only need the one but answer on both would be appreciated just for the sake of knowing and maybe future use.

Br. Anders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
$('*:not([class])')
```

You'd then be able to do

```
$('*:not([class])').addClass('gotClass');
```

or

```
$('*:not([class])').eq(3).addClass('gotClass');
```

To clarify: the selector matches all elements, `*`, that are `not` within the scope: "any element with the attribute, `[`,`]`, `class`"

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for a very fast answer

Comment: index - starts from 0. 3rd element will have index 2.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 3rd form, simply ...

```
$('form:eq(2)').addClass('gotClass');
```